# why my logic is not working to create functions?

Tags: r

I want to create a function that to read differents sheets from a worksheet of a file in Excel,I have tried many different ways to do this but I keep runnning into errors, currently, this seems to be simple:

```
hoja <- readWorksheetFromFile("data.xls",sheet=1)
x <- c("lamb","GLU")
hoja1 <- hoja[hoja[,"time"]==-5,x]
```

After that, I tried to generalized it by creating this function:

```
submatrix <- function(file, sheet,time,col){
    hoja <- readWorksheetFromFile(file,sheet=sheet) 
    hoja1 <- hoja[ hoja[,"time"] == time,col]
}
```

what does mean this error...it is not make sense for me...

```
Error: object 'hoja' not found
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Does anyone have some suggestion for me? it isnt the way to create functions?

Comment: Please add how you call your function `submatrix`.

Comment: This is most probably just a matter of how your code editor communicates (through you maybe?) with the R console. Are you using Rstudio? Or something else? What is your OS?

Comment: For what it's worth: I just copied-pasted the whole chunk of code (the function) in my R console and it worked (in the sense that I have no error and that I can use a function called `submatrix`)...

Comment: I think she's actually executing the function (working) and then she can't access `hoja` which is actually true, since it isn't returned.

Comment: @Pascal, thanks! but it is just what I think that not make sense,  it is just a code it looks like logical! I am not called a function yet and I got a mistake...upsss  am I wrong? actually I am not sure if it is necessary...thanks

Comment: @VincentGuillemot, YESS! of coursee! thank you so much!! I feel better!:)

Comment: yes @CathG I agree with you...but it is just the code, i am close the scripts and delete all variable (rm(list=ls()), i think it has to be about enviroment in R...i know it is a simple error...

Comment: This is strange! I copied and pasted your function and it does not produce any error in my RStudio. Check the code lines above and below the function is declared.

Comment: Thanks you so much! I had a problems with Rstudio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably accessing `hoja` outside that function, while you have not returned anything at all (so the last item only will be returned), causing all items but the last you have defined to be destroyed after the function finishes its work.

Try this.

```
submatrix <- function(file, sheet,time,col){
    hoja <- readWorksheetFromFile(file,sheet=sheet) 
    hoja1 <- hoja[ hoja[,"time"] == time,col]
    list(hoja, hoja1)
}
```

You can then access those items as follows:

```
 item <- submatrix(...)
 item[[1]] #refers to hoja
 item[[2]] #refers to hoja1
```